# the rank of $M$ is then defined by the dimension of the vector space $S^{-1}M$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a $A$-module, where $A$ be the commutative ring with unity. Set $S=A \setminus \{0 \}$ and $K=S^{-1}A$, which is a field. Then $S^{-1}M$ is a $K=S^{-1}A$-vector space. The rank of $M$ is then defined by the dimension of the vector space $S^{-1}M$.

My question-

$(i)$ How to show $S^{-1}A$ is a field ?

$(ii)$ How to show $S^{-1}M$ is a $S^{-1}A$-vector space ?

Comment: What have you tried? I think if you right out the relevant definitions and hypotheses you'll see a relatively clear path to what you want to prove.

Comment: More assumptions on $A$ are needed.  For example, if $A$ has a nilpotent element, your $S$ is not a multiplicative set.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR For $S$ to be closed under multiplication, you need to ensure that $s_1s_2\neq0$ for $s_1,s_2\in S$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin, why you are looking at $s_1s_2$ ?  while we have $S^{-1}A$, I think we need to assume something on $A$ not $S$

Comment: @DerekAllums, how do you see it a clear path?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR  In a sense, yes, but $S=A\setminus \{0\}$. You should revisit the definition of $S^{-1}A$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin, ok, do you think $s_1s_2 \neq 0$ is enough condition to show the result?